# Configurar KCFinder no TinyMCE

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, tinymce, kcfinder

Olá, eu estou usando o TinyMCE como campo de texto e preciso que seja possível fazer o upload de imagens nele, e para isso estou usando o KCFinder, só que o problema é que quando eu clico para fazer upload de imagens, ele aparece apenas um box em branco: segue código de inicialização do TinyMCE (Obs: estou programando em angular):

```
vm.tinymceOptions = {
        resize: false,
        height: 300,
        menubar: false,
        plugins: 'autolink link image preview fullscreen textcolor ',
        toolbar: 'undo, redo | styleselect  | cut, copy, paste | bold, italic, underline, strikethrough | subscript, superscript | alignleft aligncenter alignright | link image | preview, forecolor',
        file_browser_callback: function(field, url, type, win) {
            tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
                file: 'app/template/plugin/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=tinymce4&field=' + field + '&type=' + type,
                title: 'KCFinder - Caminho atual: ',
                width: 700,
                height: 400,
                inline: true,
                close_previous: false
            }, {
                window: win,
                input: field
            });     
            return false;
        }
    };
```

E esse é oque aparece quando abro o upload de imagem no TinyMCE:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No arquivo de configurações do KCFinder, é necessário definir a URL completa para o diretório em que as imagens ficarão armazenadas.